# Add header through intermediate micro service with Spring Boot and Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

In my spring-boot application, I have several endpoints, invoking them will send these requests to another application with RestTemplate and returns the response to the client application. My requirement is to extract an header from client service and send to target service and extract another header from target service response and set to the client's response.
I am not able to achieve this with ClientHttpRequestInterceptor due to below code structure,

Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<EntityResponse> checkValidity(RequestEntity request){
        ResponseDTO response =
            entityService.checkValidity(request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
      }
```

entityService.checkValidity(request) is invoking a json rpc method of target application.

I created an interceptor and attached to my RestTemplate, which is getting invoked properly.

```
    public class HeaderModifierInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    
      ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
      @NonNull HttpRequest request,
      byte @NonNull [] body,
      @NonNull ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
      throws IOException {
if(check to if header present in incoming request) // this is never true as I am losing the header by the time request reaches here
   request.getHeaders().add(key, value);
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
if(check to if header present in response)
   response.getHeaders().add(key, value);
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

So, I am losing the incoming header by the time it reaches the interceptor and outgoing header by the time it reaches the controller as we are only converting the bodies in the transition.

Is there any way that I can capture incoming header from client app and response header from target app during this transition?
Note: My application does not maintain the session state to preserve values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Filter to capture incoming headers and store them in a ThreadLocal variable.

Use the **ThreadLocal** variable within the **ClientHttpRequestInterceptor** to get the incoming header and add it to the outgoing request.

Capture the response header in **ClientHttpRequestInterceptor** and store it back in a **ThreadLocal**.

Use an **Interceptor or Aspect** to set the response header based on the ThreadLocal variable before the response is sent back.

```
public class HeaderCapturingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> incomingHeader = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> "");

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        incomingHeader.set(request.getHeader("Your-Incoming-Header-Name"));
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has given me a direction.